# Ruby on Rails 2 Drop Down Menus Want Validation of Selection Pre-Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a ruby on rails app that has a form. I was wondering if there is a way to make sure that a user has selected drop down menu items in both of the drop downs on this form before it is submitted and params are generated. Ideally I would like to throw and error warning them to pick 1 item on each of the drop downs and re-render the form.

The form is below:

```
<%= form_tag compare_products_path, method: :get do |f| %>
  <%= select_tag :product_id1, options_from_collection_for_select(@products, 'id', 'name') %>
  <%= select_tag :product_id2, options_from_collection_for_select(@products, 'id', 'name') %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Please let me know how I can accomplish what I stated above.

SIDENOTE: I also implemented Select2 to make the form look nicer but could not find out of there is a quick validation trick in Select2 to accomplish what I said above, if there is a suggestion for that I can post the Select2 version,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= select_tag :product_id1, options_from_collection_for_select(@products.where.not(:name=>nil), 'id', 'name'), :include_blank => "Please select...",:required=>true %>
<%= select_tag :product_id2, options_from_collection_for_select(@products.where.not(:name=>nil), 'id', 'name'), :include_blank => "Please select..." ,:required=>true %>
```

Comment: I have had problem with using "options_from_collection_for_select". I just do not understand what needs to go in the third argument 'name'?

Comment: Try this it will show all the data where name filed is not nil

Comment: Update: Implemented the above, though there is a problem, it auto selects the first option. I have a dropdown with a search field and placeholder, so I do not want the first option to be selected, I would rather have validation done at the form level to make sure the user selects an item from the dropdown, any idea how to accomplish this ?